# Event Handler: Mouse Leave Delayed Reactions

Tags: jquery, css, event-handling, jquery-animate

I have been trying to get the boxes to expand on mouse enter and un-expand on mouse leave.  I've been able to achieve this to a point; however, when I hover over an item, then shrink the browse, and hover over the item again, the object does not move back to it's rightful place.  It takes about ten seconds before it does...  Anyone have solutions?  Heres the site: http://www.snowtailcreative.com/rene_milbery/index.html

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="spotlight-item">
<h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
<p>Mauris venenatis a justo lobortis elementum. Suspendisse varius urna tristique justo sodales condimentum. Quisque et euismod massa.</p>
<p class="more-details">Quisque imperdiet nibh sed sagittis dignissim. Nullam vel massa nisi. Integer cursus libero eu semper congue. Sed pulvinar vehicula leo, quis vulputate orci. Vestibulum quis diam ipsum. Mauris venenatis a justo lobortis elementum. Suspendisse varius urna tristique justo sodales condimentum. Quisque et euismod massa.</p>
</div>
```

Here's my Applicable CSS:

```
.more-details {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Set Default Viewport Size
    var viewport = $(window).width();

    // Call Functions
    boundingBoxes ();

    // Actions On Window Resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        viewport = $(window).width();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {boundingBoxes ();}

    });

    // Bounding Boxes
    function boundingBoxes () {
        if (viewport >= 760) {
            $(".spotlight-item").on({
                mouseenter: function() {
                    $(this).children().show(600);   
                    $(this).animate({marginTop: "-190px"}, 600);
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $(this).children(".more-details").hide(600);
                    $(this).animate({marginTop: "0px"}, 600);   
                }
            });
        }
        else if (viewport < 760) {
            $(".spotlight-item").off();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: resize event handler can be called hundred times. On each call you are rebinding new hover handlers. Don't nest it inside resize handler. BTW, you should use `.stop()` or `.finish()` method for animation, depending what you are looking for

Comment: The resize event handler is used so that the viewport variable has an accurate window width so that I can disable the event handlers once the website is on mobile devices... I went a head and tried programing it outside the resize event handler, but the event handler still exists on mobile devices then....  I tried the .stop and .finish methods on my animations and both made the animation jerky and unstable....